# Regex replace is eating up the whole string! How do I make regex ungreedy?

Tags: regex, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm working with a really large spreedsheet in Open Office and I've had to learn regular expressions to clean it up.

Right now I'm trying to remove all `<span>` tags and I've come up with an expression to do so:

```
(<span.*?>|</span>)
```

The problem is that OpenOffice doesn't seem to like the question mark (which should make it ungreedy), so when I try to remove the `<span>` tags, it removes most of my string.

Here is a sample of the data: http://pastebin.com/AKWZJJCv

What is an alternative way of reming the `<span>` tags that would work in OpenOffice's find and replace?

Comment: If you observe that `.*?` remains greedy, it would point to the fact that the regular expression is not read as a perl-compatible regex (PCRE), but as, for example, Basic/Extended/POSIX regex (none of which know the `?` modifier to non-greedify `.*`)

Comment: However, OpenOffice is Java based. I would be surprised if it did not use the Java regex engine. I wonder what is going on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try `(<span[^>]*>|</span>)`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! If you don't mind me asking, what does `[^>]*` mean? I know that the `[^>]` will match the first `>`, but if the `*` means 0 or more, then why is it needed?

Comment: `[]` is the character class. `[abcd]` says "match exactly one character from the input that is either a, b, c, or d". `[^]` is the negative character class, which says "match any one character thats not in the class". I told it "match any number of characters thats not a '>', then match a '>'."

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
<(\/)?span([a-zA-z\-\="0-9 ]*)?>
```

Tested [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%3C%28%5C/%29?span%28%5Ba-zA-z%5C-%5C=%220-9%20%5D%2a%29?%3E&input=%3Cp%3EThe%20Binghamton%20region%27s%20consumer%20confidence%20index,%20a%20measurement%20of%20the%20spending%20and%20savings%20habits%20of%20consumers,%20decreased%20by%208%20percent%20this%20quarter%20—%20from%2055.1%20to%2050.8%20points%20—%20making%20it%20the%20region%20with%20the%20lowest%20consumer%20confidence%20index%20in%20New%20York,%20according%20to%20a%20study%20released%20by%20Siena%20Research%20Institute%20%28SRI%29%20last%20Monday.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan%20data-scayt_word=%22Subimal%22%20data-scaytid=%221%22%3ESubimal%3C/span%3E%20%3Cspan%20data-scayt_word=%22Chatterjee%22%20data-scaytid=%222%22%3EChatterjee%3C/span%3E,%20a%20marketing%20professor%20and%20associate%20dean%20of%20the%20School%20of%20Management,%20said%20he%20was%20already%20aware%20of%20economic%20decline%20in%20the%20region.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3E%22I%20don%27t%20need%20numbers%20to%20tell%20me%20things%20are%20bad%20and%20neither%20do%20other%20people,%22%20%3Cspan%20data-scayt_word=%22Chatterjee%22%20data-scaytid=%223%22%3EChatterjee%3C/span%3E%20said.%20%22The%20question%20is%20why%20this%20is%20so%20bad%20for%20so%20long,%20and%20the%20big%20issue%20is%20creating%20%3Cspan%20data-scayt_word=%22jobs.%22%22%20data-scaytid=%224%22%3Ejobs.%22%3C/span%3E%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3EThe%20index%20was%20measured%20on%20a%20scale%20of%20one%20to%20150%20points%20for%20nine%20metropolitan%20areas%20in%20New%20York.%20SRI%20asked%20those%20it%20surveyed%20questions%20focused%20on%20three%20core%20topics%3a%20personal%20finances,%20state%20of%20businesses%20and%20buying%20decisions.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3ESome%20shoppers%20said%20the%20ways%20they%20try%20to%20cut%20back%20their%20spending%20include%20using%20coupons,%20looking%20for%20sales,%20eating%20in%20and%20making%20less%20shopping%20trips%20to%20save%20on%20gas.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3EStacy%20Hubbard,%20a%20resident%20of%20Berkshire%20who%20was%20shopping%20at%20the%20Vestal%20Walmart%20with%20her%20husband%20on%20Sunday,%20said%20she%20now%20uses%20a%20grocery%20list%20when%20shopping%20and%20tries%20to%20avoid%20buying%20things%20that%20are%20not%20household%20necessities.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3E%22We%20try,%20but%20it%27s%20hard%20to%20save%20money%20with%20no%20more%20raises%20and%20prices%20going%20up,%22%20Hubbard%20said.%3C/p%3E).